# How to implement an iterator giving struct with lifetimes?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I want to create a mutable iterator that control modifications, for this I  create a struct named `FitnessIterMut` that `impl` the `Iterator` trait.
The `next()` method gives a struct that can do things on the container itself when a modification is done. (Is it a good way to do this sort of things ?)

```
pub struct FitnessModifier<'a, T: 'a> {
    wheel: &'a mut RouletteWheel<T>,
    value: &'a mut (f32, T)
}

impl<'a, T> FitnessModifier<'a, T> {
    pub fn read(&'a self) -> &'a (f32, T) {
        self.value
    }

    pub fn set_fitness(&'a self, new: f32) {
        let &mut (ref mut fitness, _) = self.value;
        self.wheel.proba_sum -= *fitness;
        self.wheel.proba_sum += new;
        *fitness = new;
    }
}

pub struct FitnessIterMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    wheel: &'a mut RouletteWheel<T>,
    iterator: &'a mut IterMut<'a, (f32, T)>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for FitnessIterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = FitnessModifier<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(value) = self.iterator.next() {
            Some(FitnessModifier { wheel: self.wheel, value: value })
        }
        else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me this error, I think I have to do a `'b` lifetime but I'm a little lost.

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
        Some(FitnessModifier { wheel: self.wheel, value: value })
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    if let Some(value) = self.iterator.next() {
        Some(FitnessModifier { wheel: self.wheel, value: value })
    }
    else {
        None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get this to work with simple mutable references, unless you're OK with *not* implementing the standard `Iterator` trait. That's because it's not legal in Rust to have more than one usable mutable alias to a particular value at the same time (because it can lead to memory unsafety). Let's see why your code violates this restriction.

First, I can instantiate a `FitnessIterMut` object. From this object, I can call `next` to obtain a `FitnessModifier`. At this point, both the `FitnessIterMut` and the `FitnessModifier` contain a mutable reference to a `RouletteWheel` object, and both the `FitnessIterMut` and the `FitnessModifier` are still usable – that's not legal! I could call `next` again on the `FitnessIterMut` to obtain another `FitnessModifier`, and now I'd have 3 mutable aliases to the `RouletteWheel`.

Your code fails to compile because you assumed that mutable references can be copied, which is not the case. Immutable references (`&'a T`) implement `Copy`, but mutable references (`&'a mut T`) do not, so they cannot be copied.

What could we do to fix this? Rust lets us temporarily make a mutable reference unusable (i.e. you'll get a compiler error if you try to use it) by *reborrowing* from it. Normally, for types that don't implement `Copy`, the compiler will move a value instead of copying it, but for mutable references, the compiler will reborrow instead of moving. Reborrowing can be seen as "flattening" or "collapsing" references to references, while keeping the shortest lifetime.

Let's see how this works in practice. Here's a valid implementation of `next`. Note that this doesn't conform to the contract of the standard `Iterator` trait, so I made this an inherent method instead.

```
impl<'a, T> FitnessIterMut<'a, T> {
    fn next<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Option<FitnessModifier<'b, T>> {
        if let Some(value) = self.iterator.next() {
            Some(FitnessModifier { wheel: self.wheel, value: value })
        }
        else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning an `Option<FitnessModifier<'a, T>>`, we now return an `Option<FitnessModifier<'b, T>>`, where `'b` is linked to the lifetime of the `self` argument. When initializing the `wheel` field of the result `FitnessModifier`, the compiler will automatically reborrow from `self.wheel` (we could make this explicit by writing `&mut *self.wheel` instead of `self.wheel`).

Since this expression references a `&'a mut RouletteWheel<T>`, you thought the type of this expression would also be `&'a mut RouletteWheel<T>`. However, because this expression borrows from `self`, which is a `&'b mut FitnessIterMut<'a, T>`, the type of this expression is actually `&'b mut RouletteWheel<T>`. In your code, you tried to assign a `&'b mut RouletteWheel<T>` to a field expecting a `&'a mut RouletteWheel<T>`, but `'a` is longer than `'b`, which is why you got a compiler error.

If Rust didn't allow reborrowing, then instead of storing a `&'b mut RouletteWheel<T>` in `FitnessModifier`, you'd have to store a `&'b &'a mut RouletteWheel<T>`, where `'a` is the lifetime of the `RouletteWheel<T>` and `'b` is the lifetime of the `&'a mut RouletteWheel<T>` in the `FitnessIterMut<'a, T>`. However, Rust lets us "collapse" this reference to a reference and we can just store a `&'b mut RouletteWheel<T>` instead (the lifetime is `'b`, not `'a`, because `'b` is the shorter lifetime).

The net effect of this change is that, after you call `next`, you can't use the `FitnessIterMut` at all until the resulting `Option<FitnessModifier<'b, T>>` goes out of scope. That's because the `FitnessModifier` is borrowing from `self`, and since the method passed `self` by mutable reference, the compiler assumes that the `FitnessModifier` keeps a mutable reference to the `FitnessIterMut` or to one of its fields (which is true here, not is not always true in general). Thus, while there's a `FitnessModifier` in scope, there's only one *usable* mutable alias to the `RouletteWheel`, which is the one in the `FitnessModifier` object. When the `FitnessModifier<'b, T>` goes out of scope, the `FitnessIterMut` object will become usable again.

If you absolutely need to conform to the `Iterator` trait, then I suggest you replace your mutable references with `Rc<RefCell<T>>` instead. [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) doesn't implement `Copy`, but it implements `Clone` (which only clones the pointer, not the underlying data), so you need to call `.clone()` explicitly to clone an `Rc`. [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) does dynamic borrow checking at runtime, which has a bit of runtime overhead, but gives you more freedom in how you pass mutable objects around.

Comment: That's a beautiful explanation you do here, I think I will see another way to do this, the `Rc<RefCell<T>>` is not appropriate for what I want, I need performances, And I need to use the real `Iterator` Trait too. Thanks for that, you seem to know many things on Traits and Lifetimes :)